# Humans learning strict alien ceremony where a mistake results in death

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

Science fiction short story, no idea when or who wrote it, basic plot is humans are on an alien planet.  They must attend a ceremony (dinner?) which has a strict protocol.  When the ritual is done incorrectly the human is killed.  After many attempts the humans slowly learn, step by step, the ritual.  The story is about the last human who has trained for some time for the ritual, he is successful. There is some punchline about finally housetraining humans.

Comment: Hi Mike. I took the liberty of improving your title, because I *really* want someone to answer this one :)

Comment: Not quite what you describe, as there's only one human doing the ceremony, but Heinlein's "Double Star" has as a plot element the lead character (who is doubling for the person who was supposed to do it) attending such a ceremony.

Comment: I posted this as answer, but rereading your question, I'm less convinced it is correct.  But have a look at Timonthy Zahn.  Protocol.  A description is [here](http://bestsf.net/analog-science-fiction-and-science-fact-september-2002/):

Colonists from Earth are finding it very hard to survive on their planet of choice. A very, very strange race of large, godlike humanoids have the humans following a strict protocol in terms of native/human contact. Any deviation from that protocol is met by death.

Comment: @Rori:
I say undelete the answer. Answers that don't completely match are still valid as sometimes, the querents confuse their details.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Done.  Thanks, I wasn't quite sure what the policy was.  It's a bit off, but as you say, the post is based on a vague recollection.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the ***Hungry are the Damned*** segment from the first Treehouse of Horror.

Comment: Reminds me of the Futurama episode `My Three Suns` in which Fry must perfectly recite his coronation oath, any mistake and he is killed.

Answer (score 6):

Although some of the details are a bit off, it has some resemblance to the following:

**Timothy Zahn. Protocol.**

A description from [bestsf.net](http://bestsf.net/analog-science-fiction-and-science-fact-september-2002/)

> Colonists from Earth are finding it very hard to survive on their
>   planet of choice. A very, very strange race of large, godlike
>   humanoids have the humans following a strict protocol in terms of
>   native/human contact. Any deviation from that protocol is met by
>   death.
>
> This unfathomable behaviour becomes more problematic when one of the
>   natives goes rogue. This poses the settlers with another problem in
>   terms of understanding the protocol for that situation.
>
> The story ends at that point, giving this reader a feeling of being
>   left somewhat in the lurch, having being offered a glimpse of a story,
>   but not the whole picture.

It was published in [Analog Science Fiction and Fact](https://www.analogsf.com/2015_09/index.shtml) September 2002.  I can't seem to find their archives on the website, but they are probably there somewhere.   Here's a link to that particular issue on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001ENJE3Q).

Comment: I believe you may have the right author. Timothy Zahn is old enough for me to be misremembering and he did use the protocol theme in several of his works (Pawns Gambit, Star Wars). I am not 100% but I will let the mystery rest. Thank you.